# Override CSS File

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using an optimizepress template the has a css file with the following line that is part of the theme:
`.container{width:1060px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background-color:#fff}`.

I want to override it to make the width 900px.

How can I do that without changing the css file?

Optimizepress theme has the ability to do on page css but I tried to use important but it is not working for me.

Comment: You'd a) add another CSS file after it, b) add a `<style>` block after it, or c) add an inline style `style="width: 900px;"` to the element's HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just link to another CSS file, underneath your current one. In CSS, if you have two styles for the same class, the last one the computer reads is the one that gets chosen. That's why you need to link to the new CSS after.

So make a new css file and write

```
.container {
  width: 1060px;
}
```

Then in your HTML header, directly UNDERNEATH where your linkg your current css is put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/yournewcssfile.css">
```

Comment: I added the css link to header using the theme Header code section but it adds it before the other css file.

Comment: Why can't you add it after the other css file?

Answer (score 0):

OptimziePress theme has custom CSS page where you can override the CSS. The following is the steps to locate those custom CSS areas and paste your CSS code.

> 1- Go to the OptimizePress Dashboard > Blog Settings > Modules > Other
>   Scripts > Choose 'Custom CSS' in the drop dow
>
> 2- Go to the OptimizePress Dashboard > Global Settings > Custom CSS
>   (Sitewide)

Comment: I want to do it for one specific page. I added .container {width: 900px;} to the Custom CSS of the page but it did not override the 1060px width.

Comment: Then, follow the Jordan Overbye answer for exactly one page.

Comment: His did not work because it comes up first in the css order file so it does not override it. Any other ideas?

Comment: did you use `!important` with his code?